# Force user to change password on first login

Tags: php, html, authentication

I'm creating a login module. The admin and the users use the same page for login. Based on the credentials the page directs accordingly to admin and user pages. After the admin logs in, the admin adds the users and assigns them a password. With this password the users login. My project works till here. The problem is , I have to write a script to force the user to change the password when they login for the first time.

For this, I have created a login table which consists of username,password,fname.

I'm a beginner in php. Hence stuck.

Please help me.

Login.php

```
 {
  $_SESSION['login'] = "OK";
  $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
  $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
  header('Location: adminpage.php');

}

else

{
  $_SESSION['login'] = "";

  header('Location: wrong.html');    
}
```

adminpage.php

```
 if($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin')
{
  echo "<p align=right><a href='login.php'>Log out</a></p>";     
  echo "<p><a href='create_user.php'>Create a new user</a></p>";
  echo "<p><a href='reports.php'>Reports</a></p>";

}
  elseif
  {
      header('Location: userpage.php');
  }
```

Comment: I would think you would need to store if they have logged in yet or not, so a cookie or in the database.

Comment: You can add another column to your table `first_run` if it's 0 then it's the first run if it's 1 then the user logged in before

Comment: @hungrykoala, Yes i did create a last_login column in the table. I have to check if it is NULL then , ask user to change password. I know the logic, but i do not know how to apply it.

Comment: When the user logs in to your system you check first if it's 0 or 1 if it is 0 "first run" you then redirect them to a change password page

Answer (score 0):

In your `login table` add a new column for exemple.

`status TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT -1`. 

Set it to any default value (i've suggested -1) and when user changes their password after first login, change it to 1. Check this value for login request of your user. Later you can also use this column to block user `(status = 0)`

Comment: where do i the code in login.php or admin.php? The login.php is the first page. After login the user will be directed to admin.php

Comment: @Solomon_Arvind you have to run this query in your SQL (phpmyadmin or wherever you have created your login_table). `ALTER TABLE login_table ADD status TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT -1`;

Comment: I have done that in phpmyadmin . I'm asking about the php code

Comment: wherever you are checking their credentials (like username & Pass) also fetch status from DB along with them and check status along with them

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and solved it the following way.

Inside my part of the script that verifies the hashed password against the entered password I put in this part of code in an if statement:

This is the complete code:

```
// Prepare a select statement
$sql = "SELECT id, username, password, admin, status FROM loginusers WHERE username = ?";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_username);

    // Set parameters
    $param_username = $username;

    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    if($stmt->execute()){
        // Store result
        $stmt->store_result();

        // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
        if($stmt->num_rows == 1){                    
            // Bind result variables
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $hashed_password, $admin, $status);
            if($stmt->fetch()){
                if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                    // Password is correct, so start a new session
                    session_destroy();
                    session_start();

                    // Store data in session variables and cookies
                    $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                    $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                    $_SESSION["admin"] = $admin;
                    setcookie("admin", $admin, time()+ 86400 * 30,"/");
                    setcookie("username", $username, time()+ 86400 * 30,"/");

                        // Redirect user to forced password change page
                        if($status == '0'){
                        // Redirect to first password change page
                        header("location: /login/firstpassword.php");
                        } else {
                        header("location: /index.php");
                    } else {
                        // Display an error message if password is not valid
                        $password_err = "Wrong password.";
                    }
                } else {
                    $password_err = "Error with database connection!";
                }
            } else{
                // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                $username_err = "No account with this username.";
            }
        } else{
            echo "Oops, something is wrong. Contact the website admin.";
        }

        // Close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

This is the part that forces the user to a password change page:

```
// Redirect user to forced password change page
if($status == '0'){
// Redirect to first password change page
header("location: /login/firstpassword.php");
} else {
header("location: /index.php");
```

Small addition to my earlier answer, you have to set the 'status' to anything other then 0 to make the user skip the forced password change page on every following login.

I did this on the 'firstpassword.php' page by setting the 'status' to 1 with another SQL INSERT query. So the user only get's the password change page once.

Hope this helps!